# Lazy loading data of TypeScript classes?

Tags: angular, rest, typescript

I have an Angular application which consumes a RESTful API for data. What I would like to do is structure my data objects such that I only load what I need from the server as it's needed.

For example, if I have a list of `Building` objects which each have a `tenants` property I would like the REST API to send me a building object with a `int[]` of tenant IDs instead of sending an array of `Tenant` type objects. Then in my app I could list `Building`s but only show the tenant details when I expand a details panel or something. At that point the app would fetch the individual `Tenant` objects from the RESTful API by their ID aynchronously. And this would save me from having to fetch *all* Tenants of *all* building up-front.

Is this a normal pattern in web applications? I'm having trouble finding any resources on this because I'm not sure what to search for. I would especially appreciate some Angular-specific implementations of the pattern.

Thanks!

Comment: A RESTful api, for a particular endpoint, will send all the data that it's programmed to send, whether you need it or not. The pattern of data loading that you're describing can be achieved by putting GraphQL in front of your REST api. But this is a lot of work as your API developers would need to implement this GraphQL layer.

Comment: I could just design my api endpoint for, let's say, `/api/Buildings` to just return `Building` objects with `tenants` as an `int[]` though. Then I just need to add an endpoint for `/api/Tenants/{id}` and I'm all set - I'm not struggling with the RESTful API server I'm more struggling with how to wire up the client to work this way.

Comment: Okay. I misread your question. I would advice against what you're trying to do. For e.g. for every tenant you'll need to get the tenants details from the server. That is one network request for each tenant. This will add a lot of network delay to your client app. Not to mention the amount of requests the server will need to fulfill for all the different clients asking for tenants one request at a time. At my company, we've faced this problem and ended up sending all data in one REST api endpoint. In the end we implemented GraphQL.

Comment: @AksharPatel currently in my application that is what I'm doing - returning a full `Building[]` from the RESTful API where every `Building` has a property of `tenants` which is a `Tenant[]` which is obviously more convenient but in the end I might only ever need the full details of one of those Tenants

Comment: Hi @KyleV., have you had a chance to check out my answer? Hopefully it covers whatever is best for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking this through myself. A few potential approaches:

1. **Load it all right away** - As you've mentioned, you can just return all the data from your REST server right up-front. This is convenient but doesn't scale very well, especially as you get more and more nested data structures. This may be right for you if it is only used across one level of nesting and the amount of data being loaded is relatively small for each nested object, or if performance and bandwidth are not concerns.

The remaining options are different approaches to getting the data asynchronously, where your `Building` REST route returns the Building object with a `TenantsURL` that can be used to access the tenant list.

2. **Lazy TypeScript getters**: In your class, you can hide the variable behind a getter:

   ```
   class Building {

       public constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpClient){}

       public get tenants(): Observable<Tenant[]> {
           return this.httpService.get<Tenant[]>([url here]);
       }

   }
   ```

   The downside here is that if you use tenants in an HTML template, angular will call this getter function on each change detection step (see here: [Why does this method/gettor get called X times in an Angular 2 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810807/why-does-this-method-gettor-get-called-x-times-in-an-angular-2-service#40811122)), which can become rather costly depending on latency and data size. A second downside is that now you need the HttpClient Service (or some custom derived service) injected into your models, which muddies the water between services and models.
3. **Standalone Get Function**: A slight modification of #2, instead of using a TypeScript getter just make a class method on your model that you can call:

   ```
   class Building {

       public constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpClient){}

       public constructor(){}

       public getTenants(httpService: HttpClient): Observable<Tenant[]> {
           return httpService.get<Tenant[]>([url here]);
       }

   }
   ```

   This moves the burden of providing the "getter" service (HttpClient in this example) from model construction to whomever needs to get the tenants, like an Angular component. Then you can use an Async pipe to display the values in an HTML template, or subscribe in an angular component. The downside is that, again, since this is a function it will be called every time angular does change detection, which can be a big performance hit.
4. **Pipe**: You could create a custom async pipe, `TenantPipe`, into which you could inject whatever services you need to get the Tenant data from a Building (https://angular.io/guide/pipes). Then in an HTML template you can simply use the pipe on the Building to get the list of tenants asynchronously. Note you could make your pipe asynchronous or chain it together with the existing angular async pipe if you wanted to. This has the benefit of clearly separating your models from the async get functionality, while also ensuring that angular will only run the pipe once per change detection cycle (rather than at every change detection step!). Obviously this is more HTML-template-focused, but you can inject pipes into component typescript as well so it could work there.

5. **Service**: Make a service, `TenantService` with a method `getTenantFromBuilding(building: Building): Observable<Tenant[]>`. Use this in your typescript components wherever you need. The functionality here is very similar to #4, just packaged as a service instead of a pipe with a service injected. This is more typescript-focused, but obviously whatever value you get back from the service you can display in the HTML template.

There are pros and cons to each approach, and I think selecting the right one depends on the specific situation.