# why using async filter causes to endless requests?

Tags: angular

I have simple http service that suppose to bring me collection:

```
 @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class PostService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
   getPosts(): Observable<Array<any>> {
      return this.http.get<Array<any>>(`http://localhost:9000/posts`);
   }
 }
```

According to Angular docs i can display this collection in my component using "*ngFor" by two ways:
Or:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<div *ngFor="let post of posts">{{post.title}}</div>'
})
export class AppComponent {
  posts: any[];
  constructor(public postService: PostService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.postService.getPosts().subscribe(_posts => this.posts= _posts);
  }
}
```

Or using "async" filter:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<div *ngFor="let post of posts$ | async">{{post.title}}</div>'
})
export class AppComponent {
  posts$: Observable<Array<any>>;
  constructor(public postService: PostService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.posts$ = this.postService.getPosts()
  }
}
```

My question is: why it is wrong to write following way? (it is makes sence that  all 'ngOnInit thing' can be spared):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<div *ngFor="let post of postService.getPosts() | async">{{post.title}}</div>'
})
export class AppComponent {
  posts$: Observable<Array<any>>;
  constructor(public postService: PostService) {}
}
```

I can see that is send endless requests to server, but why?

Thanks

Comment: Because the service method is called every tick, instead of just once.

Comment: why it called every tick? it is public member of component just as posts$

Comment: But posts$ is an observable that's watched for changes, calling the method returns a *new* observable each time, subscribing to which makes another request. It's not clear to me why this was unexpected.

Comment: you mean - postService.getPosts() is cold while posts$ - is hot?

Comment: It's not about hot vs. cold, the difference is between having one observable vs. many observables, calling the method once and calling it over and over again. The async pipe isn't really relevant, that's just what happens if you put a method call in a template.

Comment: posts$ = postService.getPosts()  - only stores a method call inside "posts$"

Comment: You don't "store a method call", you call the method and store what it *returns*.

Comment: I have strong feeling that the difference is evaluating observable before ngOnInit causes endless loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this method/gettor get called X times in an Angular 2 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810807/why-does-this-method-gettor-get-called-x-times-in-an-angular-2-service)

Comment: That feeling is not right.

Comment: now i see that "posts$: Observable<Array<any>> = this.postService.getPosts()" without using ngOnInit works, so i guess you right, Thanks

Comment: One more thing here - is problem is with calling method of "service" which is stateless instead of store the state inside some public memeber

Comment: There are other patterns you could use, see e.g. this blog post I wrote: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html. But you'd still see the problem if you called the trigger method from the template; again, it's not really about async/observables at all.