# Show filter result count in angular dynamically

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and I using angular10.I have one array =>

```
 var test =  [
    {
        id:1,
        type:"banana",
        isgood:true
    },
    {
        id:1,
        type:"apple",
        isgood:false
    },
    {
        id:1,
        type:"waterml",
        isgood:true
    }    
]
```

I would like to show `count` of `isgood==false` in html.

example  => `Good Fruit Count : 2`. How can I show like that?

One problem is this `isgood` is can change dynamically or runtime.So if I write method and show result in view, I will need to call this method every time I update this value.

So I would to do like that => If I want to show total count of array, I use like that `{{test.length}}`. Can I do like that => `{{test.filter(f=>f.isgood===true).length}}`?

Answer (score 1):

you could do a `filter` then `length`on he result:

```
count = test.filter(item => item.isgood === false).length
```

and to place it on html:

```
{{ test.filter(item => item.isgood).length }}
```

Comment: Thank, But it's not refreshing UI when I update the value.

Comment: I think you might need to add more code to your question... is your array coming as an observable? or how is this array getting to angular?

Answer (score 1):

Function calls or filtering pipes in a template are not a good practice. The better way would be a reactive way using subject and rxjs.

```
fruits$: BehavioSubject<Fruit[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Fruit[]>([]);
goodFruitCount$: Observable<number> = this.fruits$.asObservable().pipe(
  map(fruits => fruits.filter(fuit => fruit.isgood).length),
);
```

Then you say in template `Good fruits: {{ goodFruitCount$ | async }}`

Every change to the fruits array is a `next` call on the subject

Comment: @MoxxiManagram, Thank you, I never try like that before, It's interesting and I will check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a getter that returns the count and use that getter in the template like below :

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
    <button (click)="randomize()">Randomize</button>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of test">
          {{ item.type }} {{ item.isgood ? "is good" : "is meh" }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>Count of good : {{ goodsCount }}</div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  test: any[];
  get goodsCount() {
    console.log("called");
    return this.test.filter(r => r.isgood).length;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.test = [
      {
        id: 1,
        type: "banana",
        isgood: true
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        type: "apple",
        isgood: false
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        type: "waterml",
        isgood: true
      }
    ];
  }
  randomize() {
    const randomIndex = (Math.random() * (this.test.length - 1)).toFixed(0);
    this.test[randomIndex].isgood = !this.test[randomIndex].isgood;
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szftd4?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you for lighting me to use `get` method. I forget it. But Should I concern this get method call several times when UI up?

Comment: @Jze it is called twice when something (anything) has changed in the template. That is related with angulars change detection strategy. You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810807/why-does-this-method-gettor-get-called-x-times-in-an-angular-2-service#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=This%20is%20because%20the%20value,you%20this%20magical%20autoupdating%20binding.) for further reading.